# What is the question mark at the end of some script tag for?

Tags: javascript, html

On some webpages I meet the following script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/view-item-details.js?v1"></script>
```

what does `?v1` really stand for and why is it used?

Comment: It most likely avoids caching of an older version of the script. It forces the browser to re-download the script, if the “version” changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything behind the question mark is a parameter that is delivered to the JavaScript.
In the given case a change in the version number prevents the browser from using the cached file and instead getting it from the server.